# Статические объекты

Tags: многопоточность, java

Есть некоторая программа, которую хочу запускать в несколько потоков.

В программе есть некоторый класс BigB (создается единственный экземпляр этого класса), который считывает данные внешних ресурсов и составляет список некоторых объектов. После этого многие классы в программе используют этот список. В классе BigB этот список является статическим полем.

При запуске программы, например в 2 потока из-за этой статичности появляются проблемы: в этот список записывает почти в 2 раза больше объектов, что неправильно. 
Можно ли как-то сделать этот класс изолированным от других потоков?

**UPD**

```
public class BigB {

public BigB(int numberOfProfiles, String profilesPath) throws IOException{

    // Путь к ресурсам
    this.profilesPath = profilesPath;

    readProfilesList(numberOfProfiles);;
}

private final String profilesPath;

// Вот как раз с этими списками проблема
private static ArrayList<ModelledProfile> listOfModelledProfiles;
private static ArrayList<RealProfile> listOfRealProfiles;

private static Map<RealProfile, ArrayList<Integer>> mapFromRealProfileToListOfIdModelledProfile;

private void readProfilesList(int numberOfModelledProfiles) throws IOException {

    listOfModelledProfiles = new ArrayList<ModelledProfile>();

    listOfRealProfiles = new ArrayList<RealProfile>();

    setMapFromRealProfileToListOfModelledProfile();

    // Количество считанных профилей
    int numberOfReadProfiles = 0;

    InputStream resStream = BigB.class.getResourceAsStream(profilesPath);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(resStream);

    while (numberOfReadProfiles < numberOfModelledProfiles) {

        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        ......

    }

    resStream.close();

    scanner.close();
}

private void setMapFromRealProfileToListOfModelledProfile() {
.....
}

public static ArrayList<ModelledProfile> getListOfModelledProfiles() {
    return listOfModelledProfiles;
}
public ArrayList<RealProfile> getListOfRealProfiles() {
    return listOfRealProfiles;
}
public Map<RealProfile, ArrayList<Integer>> getMapFromRealProfileToListOfIdModelledProfile() {
    return mapFromRealProfileToListOfIdModelledProfile;
}
```

}

**UPD2**
Более детально опишу программу. Вообще программа моделирует некоторую ситуацию, в которой, можно сказать, "воюют" некоторые алгоритмы. Мне же нужно подобрать такие параметры одного алгоритма, используя которые он обыгрывает другой алгоритм.    
Для подбора параметров использую прогон по координатной сетке, которая получается декартовым произведением множеств допустимых значений параметров. Прогон по этой сетке весьма долгий процесс, по этому хочу его распараллелить. При том, хочется так изменить код, чтобы запуск программы в один поток не слишком проигрывало по времени той реализации программы, которая есть сейчас (однопоточная верясия).      
По этому мне нужно сделать так, чтобы каждый экземпляр программы не имел ничего общего с остальными экземплярами.

Comment: Не стесняйтесь, покажите код вашего BigB.

подозреваю, проблема вовсе не в статичности, а в том, что ваш синглтон не потокобезопасен.

Comment: Проблемы у вас не из-за статичности, а из-за неправильной синхронизации потоков. В любом случае, без кода вам вряд ли кто-либо поможет.

Comment: Нету потокобезопасности — значит, надо сделать. Доступ к переменной из разных потоков надо явно синхронизировать. Если вы этого не делаете, ждите крешей.

Comment: @Stas0n: Можно, конечно. Но тогда у каждого из этих объектов будут свои данные — вам надо именно так?

Comment: @Stas0n, вообще для разделения (предотвращения одновременного исполнения) доступа threads к методам класса достаточно добавить 
**synchronized** к описанию метода. Можете добавить для `readProfilesList()`.

Однако, IMHO у Вас проблемы не только с этом. Я не очень понимаю, почему при *создании одного экземпляра* BigB (как Вы утверждаете) в списках оказывается в 2 раза больше данных.

Похоже, что ошибка где-то в другом месте. 

--

Кстати, а писать такие длинные имена не устаете? Я пока их читал - почти запутался.

Comment: Имена зато отображают суть. Что касается того, почему в списке в два раза больше объектов из-за того, что программа, запущенная в 2 потока 2жды считывает данные и кладет их в один список.   
synchronized.. но ведь тогда дольше процесс считывания будет.

Comment: @VladD да, если у каждого потока будут свои списки, то это то у нужно. Это предпочтительнее, чем синхронизовать readProfilesList(). Собственно, как это сделать?

Comment: @Stas0n: ну так, я ж привёл ссылку: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: @VladD во, я тоже сначала нагугли ThreadLocal... только не понял как им пользоваться..

Comment: @Stas0n, если у каждого  потока свои списки, то зачем делать ArrayList static? 

Просто каждый поток создает свой экземпляр BigB (и в нем свои не статические ArrayList) и работает с ним. В этом случае синхронизация не нужна.

--

Если же у Вас данные во всех потоках одинаковые, то надо сделать так, чтобы эти списки (статические) создавалиь только при первом вызове конструктора. Т.е. делаете  synchronized  readProfilesList и в его начале пишите

     if (listOfRealProfiles != null) 
        return; 

до всех new ...

--

А по поводу нагуглил и т.д. - сначала книжку о Java целиком прочтите.

Comment: 1) Код приведен для однопоточной программы. Делать поля не static значит явно передавать во все классы, где используются эти списки, например, сами списки или bigB. Это не нужно. Нужно чтобы эти статические объекты для каждого потока свои были.         
2) Синхронизация нужна, когда данные одни, а они разные...    
3) > сначала книжку о Java целиком прочтите.    

Интересно, а зачем же тогда форум, раз "целиком прочтите"

Comment: @Stas0n, параллельное программирование штука довольно специфическая, поэтому для понимания  конструктивных советов желателен определенный "бэкграунд". 

И еще. Для толковых ответов Вы бы поподробнее задачу в целом описали, логику параллельной обработки данных в ней. Тогда было бы понятней зачем в BigB нужны статические списки.

--

Кстати, и вот порядок вызова методов

    resStream.close();
    scanner.close();

в `readProfilesList()` очевидно надо поменять.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите в сторону synchronizedArrayList

Comment: в скором времени перейду от списка к массиву, т.к. это шустрее работает. Что тогда делать?

Comment: А вот `synchronizedArrayList` здесь вообще не при чем. 

Он просто позволяет одновременно безопасно модифицировать один объект из нескольких потоков, а не синхронизирует их (потоков) логику.

Comment: @avp добавил комментарий в топике.. Что касается того, что вызов методов resStream.close() и scanner.close() нужно поменять, согласен

Comment: @Stas0n, прочел. 

Почему Вы не хотите завести в каждом потоке по экземпляру BigB (без статики)  а в других классах просто использовать ссылки на них?

Comment: Да, кажется все к этому идет... Просто в программе есть абстрактный класс и десяток его потомков, которые, как раз и пользуются теми самыми списками.. кажись придется каждому раздавать по ссылке на BigB